# Single quotes in MySQL query not work for concat()

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT `osid`,`os_name`,     
       (SELECT count(*)
       FROM `game_game`
       WHERE concat(',',`os`,',') LIKE ('%,`os`.`osid`,%') ) as game_count
 FROM `game_os` AS os ORDER BY `osid`
```

Two SQL tables

**game_os**

```
osid (PK)
os_name
```

**game_game**

```
game_id (PK)
game_name
os (save data format : 1,2,3) (1,2,3 = osid)
```

This SQL query, game_count never = 0

I feel maybe '%,`os`.`osid`,%'   because `os`.`osid`  in the  **' XX '** <--

How can I fix that?

I need to get how many game in some one os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `concat()` for the `like`:

```
SELECT osid, os_name,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM game_game
        WHERE concat(',', os, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', os.osid, ',%')
       ) as game_count
FROM game_os AS os
ORDER BY osid;
```

However, you can also write this using `find_in_set()`, because you are using commas for separators:

```
SELECT osid, os_name,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM game_game
        WHERE find_in_set(os.osid, os) > 0
       ) as game_count
FROM game_os AS os
ORDER BY osid;
```